# Using the DjVu tools to for background / foreground seperation?

Tags: image, image-processing, automation, background, document

I was initially looking at developing my own [background removal algorithm](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4327172/separation-of-background-foreground-layers-in-a-scanned-document) but it appears that the popular document format [DjVu](http://www.djvuzone.org/support/tutorial/chapter-compress.html) has its own foreground / background separation functions if I can only understand how to work with it.

Quoting the DjVu docs:

> DjVu has 3 basic "modes":
>
> 1. DjVuText -- black and white (bitonal) documents
> 2. DjVuPhoto -- continuous-tone images such as photos, scanned graphic art, etc.
> 3. **DjVuLayered** -- color documents such as magazines, catalogs, historical documents, etc.
>
> Compressing to DjVu with the **DjVuLayered** mode will produce files between 30KB and 100KB, of which 5 to 40KB will be used for the foreground layer, and the rest for the backgrounds and pictures.

And for the software integration:

> DjVuLibre includes a standalone viewer, a browser plug-in (for Mozilla, Firefox, Konqueror, Netscape, Galeon, and Opera), and **command line tools** (decoders, encoders, utilities).

Any ideas how I can work with the DjVu tools to separate the background and foreground of a given scanned document?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If the document is scanned from a scanner then the image is just a flat bitmap like image.  There are no layers or objects as such.  Just pixels and more pixels.  To make a DjVu into layered document it would have to be generated as a layered document.

---

Edited Answer:

Sorry, I was not aware. I did some research and you are right. The layering option needs to be turned on in the DjVu encoding settings though. The tells the encode to use a special image processing algorithm to search for foreground and background objects and it save them to separate layers.

http://djvu.sourceforge.net - DjViLibre is a C++ library that will do what you need.

WinDjView - http://windjview.sourceforge.net/ is a nice DjVu file viewer built on DjVuLibre.  It has an option to View either Foreground or Background objects.  So this would be a good way to test how good the algorithm is before digging into c++ code.

I would recommend uploading some scanned TIFF / JPEG files to http://any2djvu.djvuzone.org/ and then using WinDjView to see the results of the fore / back separation.  I uploaded 1 color JPEG document and was quite impressed with the results.

Source code for WinDjView is available at http://windjview.cvs.sourceforge.net/viewvc/windjview/windjview/ - RenderThread.cpp - The function CRenderThread::Render() is the layer splitting/viewing code for the foreground/background viewing functions in WinDjView.

Also there is a PDF document explaining how the algorithm works - "A GENERAL SEGMENTATION SCHEME FOR DJVU DOCUMENT COMPRESSION ..." - If you perform a Google search with "vincent djvu segmentation" and then click on "Quick View" link of the 1st result then you can read the PDF.  The original PDF is no longer available.

I will have to do some more testing myself.  I wonder what the licensing fees are for commercial apps ?

I hope this answers your question a little better than my first attempt.  I looked a DjVu when it first came out and overlooked this feature for some reason.

---

Additional Information

I uploaded about 10 more documents and have come to the following conclusions.  300dpi B/W images are not able to be processed by DjVu into fore/back layers.  The whole page of a B/W converted image is contained in the foreground only.  When you upload to any2djvu, it first asks you if it is a B/W or color document. When you choose B/W you lose the background processing option which supports my theory the B/W is not supported for automatic background separation.  Fore/Back separation works on Gray and Colour images.  I do not have enough scanned images to test how well it performs though.

The fact the B/W separation is not supported possibly points to part of the reason DjVu did not take off in the document management industry many years ago.  When it first came out, most computers had a difficult enough time processing, deskewing and despeckle of B/W images.  So it was not feasible to perform greyscale or color image processing and most solutions were B/W for speed reasons.  If we were working with color images back then, then DjVu would have been a very good solution.  DjVu at the time it was released, was not much use in scanning applications for OCR.  It is a great technology though even today.

Comment: @Andrew - Not quite right. Some DjVu tools do in fact offer background/foreground separation and its one of the core features of the compression. One example of usage is in comics, where the colored background is separated from the black lines. DjVu also has a remarkable set of compressors that are more advanced than JPEG. Yes, adoption should have been higher, but the best things in life are often left untouched. Go read up.

Comment: @Andrew - Thanks very much!! .. one more question, is there an offline library or app that can actually separate the layers from a single layered TIFF/BMP file? which?

Comment: I am trying to figure what you mean by offline libaray ?  Do you mean a C++ type library for background removal that has nothing to do with DjVu but performs a similar function ?  If so it would be useful to see a few documents before making any comments.  I have added more comments to my answer above.

Comment: @Andrew - Thank you again, you're extremely helpful. Yea see basically I have lots of scans of these various brochure-type images with light colored backgrounds and black/dark text. Now I'm trying to see a way to automate the background/foreground separation so I can pass it on to OCR, and I can extract the background because I need the colored background too. -- I'm linking you to a sample image - http://m2grads2008.files.wordpress.com/2008/03/brochure_color1.jpg

Comment: I initially thought there would be DjVu style apps/command line apps/DLL libraries or whatever that could do this so I asked such a question. But my basic aim is just to separate the colored background, ideally fully automatically.

Comment: In DjVu, the separation is automatically performed in the Encoder.  DjVuLibre is a C++ library that will separate out the layers.  I uploaded you JPG file and there some problems with separation.  The image resolution of 96 dpi in your image is probably too low for the algorithm to work accurately and I am sure it would prefer 200dpi+ images.  It would be worth trying a few higher resolution images.  The image I tried was a colour laser printed Invoice with backgrounds and the DjVu encoder worked perfectly.  You can always scale them back down later if the file size is a problem.

Comment: If you are looking for something other than DjVu then you are probably looking for a smart Dynamic Thresholding algorithm combined with a text blob detection algorithm (basically DjVu).  I have done a lot of searching for such an algorithm but haven't found anything useful yet.

Comment: I just fed your image into Abbyy FineReader 10 and it did a very good job of separating and reading the text ignoring the background.  If the resolution was higher I am sure the results would be even better.  You should be able to download a trial version from http://www.abbyy.com

Comment: After some more research it seems that most of DjVu has been open sourced as DjLibre.  The enhanced encoders, of which AT&T owns the patents behind the fore/back separation, have been left out which means most of the benefits of DjVu we are talking about are not available in DjLibre.  All mention of DjVu has been removed from the LizardTech web site and they have moved on to other similar technologies.  It is time to investigate other options or wait a few more years for the patents to expire.

Comment: @Andrew - I'm just looking at feeding in one image, and fully automatically getting 2 images back, back/fore bitmaps (or 1 mask image)

Comment: @Jenko.  You have two options but I believe you will need 200dpi + images to make it work with DjVu.  1. Purchase a DjVu encoder from http://www.caminova.net   You can download a trial or  2. Upload the images to http://any2djvu.djvuzone.org/ and download the converted DjVu file back to your PC.  To separate the fore/back layers you will need to use DjVuLibre to write a C++ program to open the djVu file and then save the two layers independently.  The software from http://www.caminova.net will allow conversion of all files in a directory and you should be able to automate it.

Comment: @Jenk - What library are you using for OCR ?  Why do you need separate layers ?  Is it so you can edit the files ?  Or do you need it just for getting OCR.  If it is the latter then FineReader 10 will do what you want.